# How can I use a 120v generator to power both legs of my electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, generator

I was recently gifted a Champion brand, 3550 watt, 120 v generator.  I had intended on hooking it up to my electrical panel via generator plug inlet box and interlock kit, but after doing some research I've come to realize I've got a complex problem.

In theory, I could rig something up to jumper the single hot into two separate hots and power both legs of my panel.  But, I have several MWBCs in my house, and my understanding is that would create a situation where I am overloading the shared neutral because the generator is only producing a single phase of 120v power.  Is this correct?

What are my options, other than trying to exchange or sell for a 240 v generator?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there inexpensive 120v to 240v with center tap transformers out there? They may be a substantial fraction of the cost of a new generator...

Comment: @kgutwin Yes, you often see 120/240-240/480 5 KVA transformers for $100-ish on Craigslist that would be about the right ampacity.  OP would have to ignore the 240/480 primary, and wire the 120/240 secondary to synthesize the other leg.  For thermal reasons it could only synthesize half transformer ampacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! That is correct.  ***Well done* with  the MWBC investigation**.

The cheap/fast answer is simple: Since you are familiar with MWBC, it is safe for you to rearrange your loads to place all your critical loads on one phase. For instance, that would mean powering only 1/2 of any MWBC.  Attach the 2-pole generator breaker in  the usual way, but only connect your "hot" to one leg.

For the sole purpose of researching which leg a load is on, it is OK to temporarily pull 1 wire off a 2-pole MWBC breaker, or defeat the handle-ties.  Just put it back when you're done :)

In fact make sure they are handle-tied while you are in there.

Comment: Thank you, Harper.  Just to be clear, if I get my hands on a 240v generator the MWBCs require no special treatment, correct?  I should be able to backfeed my panel and run whatever 120v loads I want (so long as the generator can handle it)

Comment: @clwhoops44 Yes, in fact I would wire your interlock and inlet for 240V even for this generator, and make an adapter cable to take you from this gen to the correct leg of the 14-30 or whatever inlet you are using.

Comment: I see the potential for a problem if a 240V appliance is switched on while only one leg of the panel is energized.  Some of the current would be introduced to the other leg at a reduced voltage.  I don't know how it would affect everything, but it sounds like a situation to be avoided.  I think you'd see some of the same effect if you try to power half of a MWBC, wouldn't you?

Comment: @mrog yes, if the MWBC also had 240V loads on it (MWBCs can concurrently support 120V and 240V loads -- if the breaker is common-trip *for that very reason*).  Unfortunately for OP, there is no good answer.  The least bad bet is that the OP *knows* the generator is 120V so hopefully will shut off 240V loads.  Whereas if the 120V generator fed both hots, you'd *never* know you were overloading neutral.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks.  So, is it fair to say that if there are no MWBCs and 240V breakers are turned off, that it doesn't matter to safety or legality whether a 120V generator is connected to just one leg or both of them?

Answer (score 2):

### One option is to get an autotransformer

These are similar to regular transformers, but they use a single winding so they don't provide isolation between the two sides. For an application like this, isolation really isn't necessary.

[Here](https://www.victronenergy.com/upload/documents/Datasheet-Autotransformer-32A-and-100A-EN.pdf) is the spec sheet for one such unit. On the second page, it shows exactly how to use a 120V generator to provide a 240V output. With this type of setup, you would connect the generator's phase and neutral to one of the phases and the center tap on the autotransformer. These are then passed through along with a new phase wire. Doing this would allow you to power both 120V legs, supplying both 120V and 240V loads.

With a two-pole breaker and an interlock kit, you could run your inlet to the autotransformer, then to your primary branch circuit panel.

Of course, autotransformers are fairly expensive and you could probably just get a 120/240V model for not much more.

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer some of the 120V circuits to a box that can be powered from the generator via a transfer switch.

Otherwise, you are correct — trying to run both legs of your power will create problems for all of your 240V circuits, and you can consider a MWBC a 240V circuit with a neutral for this purpose.  Much cheaper to buy a 240V generator than to deal with these issues.

Comment: I'm not looking to power any 240v circuits, just 120v.

Comment: you can consider a MWBC a 240V circuit with a neutral for the purposes of this answer

Comment: Can you elaborate on the potential problems with 240V circuits when powering both legs with a 120V generator?  Could it break things, or would the appliances simply not turn on?

Comment: https://www.ahouseonarock.com/midlothian-home-inspector/what-is-an-mwbc/

Apart from that, 240v is simply 2x 120v 180deg out of phase.  However, when both legs are powered from the same 120v, they are in phase, so the voltage would be 0, and your 240v appliances would not turn on.